# Building a complex-where query using ansi sql

Tags: sql

I am having a problem finding an appropriate query about this case.

Table RESERVATION

- Cod  varchar(max)
- CustomerId   varchar(max)
- Date datetime
- Status   int

Table CUSTOMER

- CustomerId   varchar(max)
- VIP  Boolean

The problem is that I do not find a way to set VIP=true if customer has greater than 10 reservation rows with status = 1. All using ansi sql.

Can you give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,  try this:

```
 Update CUSTOMER Set VIP = 1
 Where (Select Count(*) From RESERVATION
        Where CustomerId = CUSTOMER.CustomerId 
           And Status = 1) > 10
```

or

```
 Update c Set VIP = 1
 From Customer c
 Where (Select Count(*) From RESERVATION
        Where CustomerId = c.CustomerId 
           And Status = 1) > 10
```